# AttributeError: Movie instance has no attribute 'number_of_seasons'

Tags: python, html, css

i'm learning to code with python and i'm stuck on a error:

```
AttributeError: Movie instance has no attribute 'number_of_seasons'
```

So the problem is clear but i'm not sure how to solve it. Basically i created some classes and i would like to display some Movie and Series that has different attributes.

this is the **media.py** file where i created my classes and attributes:

```
class Video():
    """This class created for both common info movies and series"""
    def __init__(self, movie_title, story_line, url_poster, url_trailer, badge):
        self.title = movie_title
        self.storyline = story_line
        self.poster = url_poster
        self.trailer = url_trailer
        self.badge = badge

    def show_trailer(self):
        webbrowser.open(self.trailer)

# here i define the class called Film for all movies
class Movie(Video):
    """This class is used to create all movies"""
    def __init__(self, movie_title, story_line, url_poster, url_trailer, badge, movie_duration, movie_actors):
        Video.__init__(self, movie_title, story_line, url_poster, url_trailer, badge)
        self.duration = movie_duration
        self.actors = movie_actors

# here i define the class called Series for all series with episodes and seasons
class Series(Video):
    def __init__(self, movie_title, story_line, url_poster, url_trailer, badge, number_of_seasons, number_of_episodes):
        Video.__init__(self, movie_title, story_line, url_poster, url_trailer, badge)
        self.number_of_seasons = number_of_seasons
        self.number_of_episodes = number_of_episodes
```

Then i have the **enterteinment_center.py** file where i added only 1 movie and 1 serie:

```
import media
import fresh_tomatoes


ironman = media.Movie("Ironman",
                      "Genius, billionaire, and playboy Tony Stark, who has inherited the defense contractor Stark Industries from his father",
                      "http://cdn.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/iron-man-1-poster.jpg",
                      "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hYlB38asDY",
                      "http://i.imgur.com/45WNQmL.png",
                      "126 minutes",
                      "English")

games_of_thrones = media.Series("Games Of Thrones",
                                "The series is generally praised for what is perceived as a sort of medieval realism.",
                                "https://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/gameofthrones/images/2/2c/Season_1_Poster.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110406150536",
                                "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iGp_N3Ir7Do&t",
                                "http://i.imgur.com/45WNQmL.png",
                                "7 Seasons",
                                "12 episodes")

movies = [ironman, games_of_thrones, ironman, games_of_thrones, ironman, games_of_thrones]
fresh_tomatoes.open_movies_page(movies)
```

and the last file that creates the html is **fresh_tomatoes.py** but i will paste here only the piece of code that i think is useful for the fix:

```
    def create_movie_tiles_content(movies):
    # The HTML content for this section of the page
    content = ''
    for movie in movies:
        if isinstance(movie, Movie):
            # Extract the youtube ID from the url
            youtube_id_match = re.search(r'(?<=v=)[^&#]+', movie.trailer)
            youtube_id_match = youtube_id_match or re.search(r'(?<=be/)[^&#]+', movie.trailer)
            trailer_youtube_id = youtube_id_match.group(0) if youtube_id_match else None

            # Append the tile for the movie with its content filled in
            content += movie_tile_content.format(
                movie_title=movie.title,
                poster_image_url=movie.poster,
                trailer_youtube_id=trailer_youtube_id,
                film_badge=movie.badge,
                film_description=movie.storyline
            )
        elif isinstance(movie, Series):
            # Extract the youtube ID from the url
            youtube_id_match = re.search(r'(?<=v=)[^&#]+', movie.trailer)
            youtube_id_match = youtube_id_match or re.search(r'(?<=be/)[^&#]+', movie.trailer)
            trailer_youtube_id = youtube_id_match.group(0) if youtube_id_match else None

            # Append the tile for the movie with its content filled in
            content += movie_tile_content.format(
                movie_title=movie.title,
                poster_image_url=movie.poster,
                trailer_youtube_id=trailer_youtube_id,
                film_badge=movie.badge,
                film_description=movie.storyline,
                serie_season=movie.number_of_seasons
            )

    return content

def open_movies_page(movies):
  # Create or overwrite the output file
  output_file = open('fresh_tomatoes.html', 'w')

  # Replace the placeholder for the movie tiles with the actual dynamically generated content
  rendered_content = main_page_content.format(movie_tiles=create_movie_tiles_content(movies))

  # Output the file
  output_file.write(main_page_head + rendered_content)
  output_file.close()

  # open the output file in the browser
  url = os.path.abspath(output_file.name)
  webbrowser.open('file://' + url, new=2) # open in a new tab, if possible
```

So basically movie and series has some different attributes so if i want to display for example numbers of seasons for Games of Throne i will get an error telling that the movie Ironman don't have any attribute called numbers of season.

hope somebody can help on this! thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the same function to extract values for classes with different attributes.

You need to assign a default value for each attribute in each class , or change the function to check the type of the `movie` in your loop.

For example :

```
for movie in movies:
    if isinstance(movie, Movie):
        # add movie attributes to the content
        content += movie_tile_content.format(
            movie_title=movie.title,
            poster_image_url=movie.poster,
            trailer_youtube_id=trailer_youtube_id,
            film_badge=movie.badge,
            film_description=movie.storyline,
            serie_seasons='no season'
            )

    elif isinstance(movie, Series):
        # add series attributes to the content
        content += movie_tile_content.format(
            movie_title=movie.title,
            poster_image_url=movie.poster,
            trailer_youtube_id=trailer_youtube_id,
            film_badge=movie.badge,
            film_description=movie.storyline,
            serie_seasons=movie.number_of_seasons
            )
```

This pattern allow you to change the content depending on the type of the media/video.

You may need to import the types in your second file:

```
from media import Movie, Series
```

Comment: I didn't really understand, how should i add this code to my file ? And what you mean import the types ?

Comment: thanks okay i added also the import to the last file and no errors, but is not launching anymore the html website

Comment: So i have imported the types but is not launching anymore the website, i will add the rest of the fresh_tomatoes.py so you can check, maybe as you said is more easy to add a default value in each attribute of each class ?

Comment: it depends on the results you want finally. But In the new code, when you use format(), you need to specify all parameters, `serie_season` is missing in the movie part, and no need to double the youtube query, you can let it outside/before the type check

Comment: `File "C:\Users\andre\Desktop\movie_website\fresh_tomatoes.py", line 181, in open_movies_page
    rendered_content = main_page_content.format(movie_tiles=create_movie_tiles_content(movies))
  File "C:\Users\andre\Desktop\movie_website\fresh_tomatoes.py", line 160, in create_movie_tiles_content
    serie_season="no season"
KeyError: 'serie_seasons'` getting this error here :( i don't understand why

Comment: my bad, i forget the 's'  in serie_seasons

Comment: Omg it works man ! man you are awesome and really thanks for the help ! I passed 3 days to find a solution! yuppy really happy now! I learned something new today :D

Comment: for this case, if you only change the season numbers, you could also define this attribute in your parent class Video() `self.number_of_seasons='n/a'`. But what you did now allows you to change all the content

Comment: Wow thanks man i appreciate a lot ! nice to know! thanks really again for your time :D